# How can I open a specific page in my app when the user clicks a link from an outside source?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, password-recovery

I'm trying to implement a password recovery feature for my mobile app (built with `Xamarin.Forms`).

The app will have a backend API in Azure, but so far I'm testing in localhost.

The idea is to make available an option to reset the user password by sending a request to the API (checking if the email exists in the database) and sending an email with a specific URL registered in the app.

I understand what I have to do in the backend, it's the app link to open a page in app that I'm interested in (Android and iOS).

Is there anyway of doing this?

Comment: Are you asking the logic for the backend or for your xamarin app?

Comment: Xamarin app integration with app links. I'm asking if there's any way to create an "app link" to open my app, like `myapp:\\open.page`.

Comment: Check about Deep Linking with Xamarin Forms, you'll have to handle native on all the platforms

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. I won't copy all the configurations, but [here is a complete tutorial](https://www.xamboy.com/2019/01/08/applinks-in-xamarin-forms/) on how to achieve that.

Comment: This means that if I sent a link to the user containing some parameters like a token, the app will be able to read that token?